# 'Proceed to Checkout' Event for Magento?

Tags: magento

I've just started putting together a Magento module which bypasses the whole Magento checkout process and instead sends the cart details to a 3rd party fulfilment company via XML-RPC.

Not getting anywhere fast and could use a bit of guidance. My understanding is that I should create the module with an observer based on the event triggered by proceeding to checkout. Trouble is I can't work out which event that would be, I've been through the whole massive list here;

http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento_events_cheat_sheet/

I've tried;

checkout_submit_all_after - fires after order processed successfully

checkout_cart_add_product_complete - fires after product added to cart

checkout_cart_save_before - fires after product added to cart

checkout_type_onepage_save_order - can't get this to fire at all

checkout_onepage_controller_success_action - fires after order processed successfully

I don't know if this means I'll have to create a custom event or if there is an entirely different and much better alternative to what I'm doing.  Building and sending the XML I will leave to another question (starting to realise I may have my hands pretty full here) but any tips there gratefully appreciated too.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index` should be the event you're looking for.  All controllers inherit the preDispatch method which fires a generic event for predispatch, and a specific event based on the requested action path. The controller you want lives in the `checkout` module and is called `onepage` with a default action of `index`.

Review `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::preDispatch()` to see the relevant code

Comment: Superb - answer much appreciated. I had started to think that as the button for checkout just had an onclick event I could alter that and process the XML and redirect using procedural PHP.  That would have taken it all out of the Magento system though. This has taken my learning forward another step!

Comment: Is the onepage controller event generic enough that it cannot be bypassed? For instance I use an extension OnePageCheckout from IWD and I can't see this event being fired. Is there a "more generic" option?